# Start and end days of the next month in Fullcalendar month view

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I need to get the Start and the End dates of the next/ preview month view when click the next or preview buttons in the Full Calendar.

Ex : Say current viewing month is January and when I click next button I need to get start and end dates February calendar view or when click preview button it should return December.

$('#calendarId’).fullCalendar('getView').start  will return current view start and end dates
but i need to returning the other month (next or preview) start and end dates.

---

Explain : I am in the month view and i can get the all the start and end dates and current dates etc by using the available options in the calendar. But I need is just assume I have to obtain the next month start date and end date before i go the next or preview view by clicking next/preview button.

Comment: Which specific event do you want these dates?

Comment: Event is when i click the next or preview buttons. I just need get start and end dates of changing view before visible them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like if you are in the month view all you need is the month and year you have navigated to. From the month and year you can determine the begin and end date of that month. http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/getDate/.

From doc:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
```

To enable caching:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    events: {
        url: '/myfeed.php',
        cache: true
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am in the month view and i can get the all the start and end dates and current dates etc by using the available options in the calendar. But I need is just assume I have to obtain the next month start date and end date before i go the next or preview view by clicking next/preview button.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I am developing a responsive event calendar component with full calendar. Since i am using lots of back end processes i need to limit ajax calls when populating the events. Hence i am doing kind of lazy loading trick when navigating the month view of the full calendar. In that case i need those date rages. Thanks!

Comment: fullcalendar has caching, you can enable that also?

Comment: Thanks MarCrazyness. I used default caching and events(as a function) feature in the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,
I used default caching and events(as a function) feature in the Full calendar. http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs2/event_data/events_function/